# filter search bar not showing up

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, filter, jsx

I'm trying to create a filtering search bar to sort through a limited set of data pulled from an API. The code compiled successfully, however despite having an `input` set to generate the search bar, it is not visible. Here is my `FilterSearch` component, where I'm trying to implement the filter and pull the results through my `StudentInfo` component.

Here is the `FilterSearch` component:

```
const USERS = "https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students";
export default function FilterSearch() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(" ");
  const [foundUsers, setFoundUsers] = useState([]);

  const filter = (keyword) => {
    setName(keyword); 
    if (!keyword || keyword !== " ") {
      setFoundUsers([]);     }
    axios.get(USERS).then((listStudents) => {
      console.log(listStudents);
      const results = listStudents.data.students.filter((data) => {
        return data.students.name
          .toLowerCase()
          .startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase());
      });
      setFoundUsers(results);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form>
        <input
          type="search"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => {
            console.log(e.target);
            filter(e.target.value);
          }}
          className="input"
          placeholder="Filter"
        />
        ;
      </form>

      <div className="user-list">
        {foundUsers && foundUsers.length > 0 ? (
          foundUsers.map((name) => <StudentInfo name={name} />)
        ) : (
          <h1>No results found!</h1>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more context, here is my `StudentInfo` component:

```
import "./StudentInfo.css";

export default function StudentInfo({ info }) {
  return (
    <div className="StudentInfo">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-3">
          <img
            src={info.pic}
            alt={info.firstName}
            width={200}
            className="img-fluid pics"
          />
          <hr />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-9">
          <h1 className="name">
            {info.firstName} {info.lastName}
          </h1>
          <h2>Email: {info.email}</h2>
          <h2>Company: {info.company}</h2>
          <h2>Skill: {info.skill}</h2>
          <h2>Average: {info.grades[0]}</h2>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: USERS is set to a string URL. You'll have to add an actual API call there to USER data

Comment: @Aneesh, this may be a silly question but do I need to make a whole function with the API call or can I get it to work with a single line? i.e. do I need to do something like `axios.get(apiUrl).then(listStudents)` or create a variable that uses the API call?

Comment: This `axios.get(apiUrl).then((listStudents)=>{ // use the data here })` is exactly what you need to do. Once the call completes, the data is avaialable in the `then` function. That's what you have to use

Comment: @Aneesh I tried to create an API call like this but I'm not sure where to call that `listStudents` function that I created. Where is the best place to implement it, just so it can pull from the API list?

```const USERS = "https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students";
export default function FilterSearch() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(" ");
  const [foundUsers, setFoundUsers] = useState(USERS);

  const filter = (e) => {
    const keyword = e.target.value;
    axios.get(USERS).then((listStudents) => {
      setFoundUsers(foundUsers);
    });
```

Comment: I've added an answer with how to use the listStudents returned from API

Answer (score 0):

So once you have the user list from the API, you can pass it into the setter function to directly update the `foundUsers` state as follows:

```
const USERS = 'https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students';
export default function FilterSearch() {
    const [name, setName] = useState(' ');
    const [foundUsers, setFoundUsers] = useState(USERS);
    const filter = (e) => {
        const keyword = e.target.value;
        axios.get(USERS).then((listStudents) => {
            setFoundUsers(listStudents); // this is where you will use and pass the listStudents
        });
    };
}
```

Also, assuming your `foundUsers` will be coming in an array, you should set initialize it to an empty array instead of the `URL` itself

`const [foundUsers, setFoundUsers] = useState([]);`

Edit:

You want the input to take the default value of your state. Also you need to update that state whenever a change happens

```html
<input
    type="search"
    value={name}
    onChange={(e) => {
        filter(e.event.target);
    }}
    className="input"
    placeholder="Filter"
/>;
```

Now you can change the filter function as follows:

```
const filter = (keyword) => {
    setName(keyword);   // we update the value of name first so that you see it update on the UI
    // let's not wait until after the API call, if keyword is empty, no need to process anything
    if (!keyword || keyword !== ' ') {
        setFoundUsers([]); // since there are no users to be found we set it to an empty array
    }
    // now that we know we have a legitimate keyword, we continue processing via api call
    axios.get(USERS).then((listStudents) => {
        const results = listStudents.filter((user) => {
            return user.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase());
        });
        setFoundUsers(results);
    });
};
```

Comment: So, I updated per your suggestions, but the search bar won't populate when I type into it now. I was trying to tweak here and there, but it doesn't appear to be working. I was trying to get the `name` value to fill back in like it had before I started trying to filter, as it now seems disconnected but I'm not sure where it's not working. I've updated the code in my original question to show what I have now. I appreciate you working with me on this, btw.

Comment: Happy to help :) I've updated the answer, it should start working now. Please take a look. Hope this helps

Comment: I used the code you suggested and while it compiles with no errors, I still don't see anything type in or filter. The console says the `e.event.target` is undefined so it can't read the properties. I substituted other variables present, like `name`, `keyword`, etc. but it's still undefined. I can tell it recognizes something is typed, since every time I type a letter, the console immediately updates, just with the undefined issue. I appreciate you breaking down the steps, it's super helpful!

Comment: You can `log` the event and share the content you get. It will help identify which key to use. Use `console.log(e)` instead of  `console.log(e.target.value)`. Also logging `e` might log a super big object, if that happens, try `console.log(e.target)`

Comment: There's progress here - I now can see the values I'm typing in and the console updates every time - it's `filter(e.target.value);` -the only issue is now it says `listStudents.filter` is not a function (uncaught in promise) even though it's been built out that way here `const results = listStudents.filter((user) => {
        return user.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(keyword.toLowerCase());
      });` 
It still compiles successfully though, even though I'm trying to tweak it to see if it'll work.

Comment: That's great to hear that some progress has been made. I would suggest updating the question to the latest version of the code so we can move ahead from there

Comment: ok so try logging the listStudents sometimes APIs return data like response.data
so what you are looking to use might actually be in listStudents.data

Comment: i did and found that it logs the info differently. while it worked to a degree for `data.students` when running `console.log(listStudents)` it changes to `data` and instead of individual students, lists out their specific items (first name, last name, etc). it still has a problem with `name` since there isn't technically "name" in the array. how do i get it to pay attention to whether someone types in either part of a first or last name and filter? i considered `let name = {data.firstName} || {data.lastName}` serve as a variable but it wasn't working